# Unable to get division to work in my program

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my python program to make a division table and my terminal keeps giving me this error when I try to run it:

> File divisiontable.py,     Enter a Number:4 Enter a start:0 Enter an
> end:100 Traceback (most recent call last):   File divisiontable.py,
> line 24, in 
> w = tablep()   File divisiontable.py, line 10, in tablep
> s = str(n) + "/" + str(i) + "=    " + str(n//i) ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

This is the program:

```
def tablep():
    n=int(input("Enter a Number:"))
    start=int(input("Enter a start:"))
    end=int(input("Enter an end:"))

    file=open("div-table.txt","a")

    if start<end:
        for i in range(start,end+1):
            s = str(n) + "/" + str(i) + "=  " + str(n//i)
            file.write(s)
            file.write("\n")
            print(n,"/",i,"=",n//i)

    elif start>end:
        for i in range(start,end,-1):
            s = str(n) + "/" + str(i) + "=  " + str(n // i)
            file.write(s)
            file.write("\n")
            print(n, "/", i, "=", n // i)

    file.close()

w = tablep()
```

I don't have any idea what this error means. I'm using python version 2.7.18 and python version 3.8.5. How would I go about getting this program to work? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Python's division operator is a single forward slash, not a double forward slash. So ```n / i``` instead of ```n // i```.

Comment: @TARN4T1ON, you are wrong `//` is for int division. The code works for me (of course I removed reading the file).

Comment: @TARN4T1ON--actually the double slash works and is used to signal integer rather than float point division.  I tried the program in Python 2.7 and it works so not sure of the issue.

Comment: You really should have included the ENTIRE error message, it would have made the problem obvious.

Comment: Why are you entering 0 for start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible to divide by 0 , start must be not equals to 0

Comment: How do I get the program to make my table start with "4/0=    0" and end at "4/100=    0.04"? Thanks.